# Can one indirect object be used to describe more than one topic?

Tags: grammar

I wanted to ask about this paragraph:

> The Lapita people discovered and settled the Samoan Islands around 3,500 years ago. They developed a unique Samoan language and Samoan cultural identity.

As seen in the above paragraph, the word "a" is used before "unique": does that mean the word "unique" just describes the Samoan language alone, or does it describe the Samoan language and Samoan cultural identity, as both being unique?

Comment: It might look the same, but wouldn’t it be the *word* ‘a’ rather than the *letter*?